# SIM7080G MFF2 SIM not detected

Tags: rf, at-commands, sim, simcom, lte

I have designed and assembled a custom PCB with ESP32 and SIM7080G LTE-M modem, basically an IoT weather station.

[SIM7080G datasheet](https://www.texim-europe.com/Cmsfile/SMM-SIM7080G-Hardware-Design-V1.04-DS-200525-TE.pdf)

Everything works fine except for a very important part that renders my project completely useless: The LTE-M modem does not detect the MFF2 SIM card, it says error SIM not inserted.

Here is the SIM circuit provided in the datasheet and mine:
(R1, R2 and R9 are 22 Ω)
(Stackup is 4 layers: signal/power, GND, GND, signal/power)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried to put a 22 μf capacitor in addition to the 100 nf cap, no change.
I have tried to remove the 22 Ω resistors, still no change.
I am completely stuck and have no idea as to why it does not work.

SIM_VDD is 0 V instead of 1.8 V but apparently the voltage is supposed to be at this level when no SIM card is detected.
Another SIM7080G modem bought at the same time, within an older version of my PCB with regular SIM socket worked with a micro SIM from the same service provider.

Do you have any idea what I could do next?